# Connecting to HipChat XMPP via jabber.el

Tags: jabber

I'm trying to connect to HipChat via jabber.el. Here is my configuration:

```
(setq jabber-account-list '(("myhipchatid@chat.hipchat.com"
                             (:network-server . "chat.hipchat.com")
                             (:password . "secret"))))
```

When I try to connect using `jabber-connect` I continually get this error:

> nil@nil: connection lost: `Couldn't connect to nil:5222: binding stack
>   not balanced (serious byte compiler bug)'

This leads me to believe that jabber-connect is not picking up the values I set in jabber-account-list. Can anyone provide guidance?

For what it's worth I've been working off of this gist: https://gist.github.com/puffnfresh/4002033

*Final update*: thanks all for the help! I've written up the final form of my working configuration here: https://gist.github.com/bitops/77308b347bceb54302a2

Comment: As the message explains, this error should never happen and seems to hint at a bug in the byte-compiler, i.e. unrelated to jabber.el.  I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` trying to give as many details as possible to try and make this problem reproducible.

Comment: @Stefan I don't think that's it - if you look at the error message you can see it's trying to connect to "nil" - that's never going to work. It should be trying to connect to something at chat.hipchat.com.

Comment: You might be right, but the rest comes from an error signaled by the byte-interpreter and that error is *very* unusual and indicates something is *seriously* wrong somewhere.  Maybe the two are unrelated, but that would be a curious coincidence.

Comment: @Stefan hm, that's interesting. Do you have any experience troubleshooting issues like that? I'm not really sure where to begin.

Comment: As mentioned, I suggest you start by reporting it as a bug in Emacs.  Try to make a good recipe to reproduce the problem.  And try to report the backtrace you'll hopefully get after enabling "Options => Enter Debugger on Error".

Comment: @Stefan I'll try debug on error. The thing that really confuses me is that I've looked at the source for the 'jabber-connect' function and it's like it's not even picking up the value I've defined for jabber-account-list. It seems like it's either something stupid simple or really crazy.

Comment: @Stefan is it a clue at all that I don't have any .elc files? I cleaned them up a while ago and I think I turned byte compilation off. I share my setup between multiple machines so I wonder if that's related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use that same gist to connect and had some troubles. Very different troubles, but troubles none the less. I needed to set certain ssl variable values, and add some options to the account as follows in order to get connected:

```
(setq ssl-program-name "gnutls-cli"
      ssl-program-arguments '("--insecure" "-p" service host)
      ssl-certificate-verification-policy 1)

(setq jabber-account-list `(("xxxxxx_yyyyyyy@chat.hipchat.com" (:port . 5223) (:connection-type . ssl))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Connecting as `nil@nil` is something that would happen if you type `M-x jabber-connect` and hit `RET` at the prompt.  (This is a bug.) `jabber-connect` lets you specify any JID to connect as, and only uses `jabber-account-list` as a source for tab completion.

Try `M-x jabber-connect-all` instead; it will pick up any and all accounts specified in `jabber-account-list`.

(The byte compiler error sounds exciting, but it might not be directly related.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I accepted Jordon's since it got me to the endgame but your input really helped me out. It is much appreciated.